# How to design database schema for table tennis tournament?

Tags: database-design

I am developing a table tennis scoring system, with Postgres, and I ran into problems. There are going to be multiple types of games played, 1v2, 2v2, or a tournament of teams.

So now I have trouble designing the correct schema for the database.

I now have these tables:

- `tournaments`
- `games`
- `teams`
- `results`
- `players`

[image: schema]

The `games.teamA`/`games.teamB` will include either one or two players' data, so this way I can determine if this is 1v1 or 2v2. If it is 1v1 the `tournament_id` would be NULL.

In the end, I would want to display a bracket if there is a tournament.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: players need a teams reference also a archve where you save in which teams where players and results doesn't look right sets won and lost can be extracted by a quuery so don't save it as long you din't want it as snapshot